# No images from SD card are shown in PTP mode

Tags: usb, photos, 9.0-pie, mtp

I have ASUS ZenFone Max Pro M2 with latest updates installed (Android 9, 070 firmware version)
I try to connect my phone to PC (Arch Linux 64 bit, Cinnamon DE, Nemo file manager, latest updates installed, `gvfs-gphoto2` and `gvfs-mtp` packages are installed too).

When I connect my phone via USB it suggests different modes for connection: charging, MIDI, modem, file transfer and PTP (*strange thing: where is MTP?*). When I choose file transfer I can see the whole directory structure for SD card and for internal storage, that just works fine.

However, when I select PTP mode I can see only directtories from internal storage (e. g. DCIM, Instagram etc) and no dirs from SD card. I already have DCIM/Camera directory tree on SD card and camera app saves photos and videos to it properly.

I tried to clear cache & data for External storage and Media storage apps and reboot but nothing changed - still no directories from SD card are shown when I select my device in Nemo file manager.

How can I enable access to SD card in PTP mode? Additionally, where is MTP mode and how I can enable it?

**EDIT 1**: seems like "File Transfer" is synonym for MTP

Comment: File Transfer must be the MTP mode. I don't think Android provides any other method for file transfer. Not sure about PTP how it's implemented.

Comment: Yes, seems like "File Transfer" is MTP actually - in Nemo I see `mtp://` prefix in address bar while connecting in File Transfer mode